# Laptop never wakes up

Tags: laptop, lid

Today I installed latest Ubuntu on my laptop but anytime I open lid, laptop never wakes up or responds so I have to restart it. I was Googling a little but nothing seems to be working. I'm also using proprietary NVIDIA driver.

Comment: Does the hardware wake up? (For example, the fan turns on?)

Comment: Yes, everything works. Only thing I see in screen is `_` in top left corner and my only option is to reboot. I had Debian before and I had same problem with opening the lid (never resolved it though).

Comment: What happens if you press CTRL+ALT+F1 when you get the blinking underscore?

Comment: @AndroidDev It's not actually blinking. I managed to get to Terminal like UI where system outputs something like 'Clearing orphaned ...' and asks me for login but it seems like it freezes and I have to restart anyway.